# Conflict on generated R

Tags: android, android-library

I has some Android projects that I'm integrating on one.

This is something like:

(Lib projects)
Android_Commons
RichReader
FacReader
WWReader

The main project is ReaderShelf, and add all those projects as library on it's path.

But the source linked presents compilation errors, the ids from the library cannot be found on the R class.

I opened all the R files, and they are a merge of all the original R files.

But when opening from the source that give error:

```
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.r_search);
    sectionsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.r_sections);
    navigateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.r_navigate);
```

They open the correct file but without the r_sections & r_navigate.

PS: r_search that don't give error is a common id that is presented on the Main project as well

Actually, I found another weird behavior, commenting the problematic lines, the code compiles, but when opening, the DPReaderActivity returns null on all findViewById.

Edit:
I saw the log building the project and I found this, I don't know if it helps

```
[2011-09-26 18:36:21 - ReaderShelf] trying overlaySet Key=r_favorites.png
[2011-09-26 18:36:21 - ReaderShelf] trying overlaySet Key=r_library.png
[2011-09-26 18:36:21 - ReaderShelf] trying overlaySet Key=r_navigate.png
[2011-09-26 18:36:21 - ReaderShelf] trying overlaySet Key=r_search.png
[2011-09-26 18:36:21 - ReaderShelf] trying overlaySet Key=r_sections.png
```

Comment: The code doesn't complie although you're using your project main `R` class which atually contains the needed (and merged from other library project `R` files) ID definitions? Am I getting this right?

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to use any R, I just added another project and this error starts to happen in the included src files.

Answer (score 2):

Check the import list, there might be an import with an outdated package name or with "R" in the name.

Comment: Specifically, check for import android.R;

Comment: I checked, this package appoints to the correct R package class (path from library)

Comment: (1) if any of the projects in your library contain manifests make sure the target sdk matchs your main project, (then rebuild)

Comment: (2) In Eclipse, choose Project > Properties > Make sure "IsLibrary" is ticked ON.